# Do professional markers stain each other?

Tags: illustration

When using professional markers (like Letraset Promarker or Copic markers), is there a risk of having ink from one colour stain or dirty another marker when drawing over it?

For example, if I draw a red area, and then draw over it with a light beige, could the beige pen pick up some of the red, and then draw a pinkish tone on consequent strokes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, when you reapply thick layers of color they will pick up color below. This enables you to blend the colors. The tip color pressure will keep the color localized on the tip, so by drawing a bit on scrap paper will clear the issue (Unless you just leave it in the nib). You can also transfer color from one nib to another and use this as a blending reservoir. They even sell empty markers, that only contain the solvent, for this purpose.

If your color has dried well then it takes a bit of time for the old layer to wet so it does not instantly do this. So if you apply thin layers after carefully dried previous layers you avoid this. Different paper stock react differently however.

Answer (score 2):

Best contact the manufacturer - most of the high end markers (i used pantone markers) you can buy spare nibs for. Water based and alcohol based inks act differently and are designed to blend but different effects can be achieved depending on surface and using a blending tool.